# How to make sidebar menu works wiith mobile?

Tags: menu, sidebar

When someone open the page with phone I want the menu to look like this:

[image]

```css
#side-menu {
 background-color: #581845;
 padding: 0px;
}

#side-menu h1 {
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 10px 0px;
 font-size: 25px;
}

#side-menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#side-menu a {
 padding: 15px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 16px;
 display: block;
}

#side-menu .glyphicon {
 margin-right: 6px;
}

#side-menu a:hover {
 background-color: #000;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
}

#side-menu .active a {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #293846;
}

#side-menu .settings-btn {
 background-color: #1ab394;
}

#side-menu .settings-btn a {
 color: #fff;
}

#side-menu .settings-btn a:hover {
 background-color: #1ab394;
}

#side-menu .collapseable li {
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-top: 5px;
}

#side-menu .collapseable a {
 color: #9fb1c2;
 font-size: 13px;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
}

#side-menu .collapseable a:hover {
 color: #fff;
}

#side-menu .collapseable {
 border-left: 4px solid #1ab394;
 background-color: #293846;
}

#side-menu .link>ul>li {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}


/*-- side-menu end --*/

.display-table {
 display: table;
 padding: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.display-table-row {
 display: table-row;
 height: 100%;
}

.display-table-cell {
 display: table-cell;
 float: none;
 height: 100%;
}

.valign-top {
 vertical-align: top;
}

#nav-header {
 background-color: #000;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
}

#nav-header #header-search-field {
 padding-top: 17px;
 vertical-align: center;
 border: none;
 width: 300px;
 outline: none;
}

#nav-header ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
 color: #676a6c;
}

#nav-header ul li {
 float: right;
 margin-left: 15px;
 padding: 17px 0px;
}

#nav-header ul .glyphicon {
 color: #676a6c;
}

.label-meassage {
 background-color: #1ab394;
}

#nav-header ul a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

#nav-header .logout {
 color: #676a6c;
}

#nav-header .logout:hover {
 color: #676a6c;
}

#nav-header #welcome {
 margin-right: 20px;
}

#nav-header ul .label {
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -10px;
 margin-left: -5px;
}

#nav-header .fixed-width {
 width: 35px;
}

.navbar-default {
 background-color: #000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
 border-color: #1ab394;
 background-color: #1ab394;
}

.navbar-default .icon-bar {
 border: 1px white solid;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
 background-color: #1ab394;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
 background-color: #1ab394;
}

#admin-footer {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0px;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #676a6c;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid display-table">
<!-- start container-fluid -->
<div class="row display-table-row">
<!-- side menu -->
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-1 hidden-xs display-table-cell valign-top" id="side-menu">
   <h1 class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">test</h1>
   <ul >
      <li  class="link">
         <a href="index.php">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">test1</span>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li  class="link">
         <a href="add.php">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">test2</span>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="link">
         <a href="#">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">test3</span>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/hani-younan/pen/ajwLqb)

Comment: Please always provide a [mcve]. Please read that link and make sure that the code you post in your question is **minimal** (only bare minimum of code necessary to reproduce), **complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **verifiable** (we can reproduce the issue using only the code in your question). codepen.io links don't count as an MCVE. Without an MCVE **in your question**, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. I [edit] the code into the question, in the future please do it on your own!

Comment: okay sir 
sorry about that , I just don't know how to add code here !
Thanks.